# Тема для WordPress, оптимизированная для pagespeed

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

Посоветуйте тему для WordPress, оптимизированную для pagespeed, есть ли такие темы?.
Предполагается использовать для сайтов-визиток, корпоративные сайты.
И чтобы можно было использовать конструктор, к примеру WPBakery Page Builder.
Покупали уже несколько тем на `themeforest.net` для WordPress, но google pagespeed выдаёт низкие показатели и при этом предпринимались попытки оптимизировать сайт с помощью таких плагинов, как `autoptimize` и подобные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Темы на themeforest обычно перегружены всякими дополнениями на все случаи жизни, что увеличивает размер кода и создаёт проблемы при оптимизации по PageSpeed.

Лучше использовать бесплатные темы из официального репозитория WordPress, созданные специально для быстрого откликаи SEO, такие, как GeneratePress, Astra, Ocean WP.

Comment: а если установить на предложенные вами темы конструктор WPBakery Page Builder, он ведь также может влиять на понижение показателя pagespeed?

Comment: Он всегда утяжеляет проект - какую тему не возьми. Elementor существенно быстрее.